# Woocommerce add extra field to variation product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/) on how to add an extra field to my variation products.

I just need to add an extra text field. The admin part works fine - the field is showing and saving/updating, however, **the single product page doesn't - the field won't show**.

So in my `functions.php` I've added:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );

function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_text_field[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'Some label', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => '',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Some description.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_text_field', true )
        )
    );
}

function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {
    $text_field = $_POST['_text_field'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $text_field );
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_settings_fields' );

function load_variation_settings_fields( $variations ) {

    $variations['text_field'] = get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], '_text_field', true );

    return $variations;
}
```

And in `plugins/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php` I've added (the theme doesn't have it's own `variation.php`):

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field">
    {{{ data.variation.text_field }}}
</div>
```

How to display the custom field on the single product page?

Thanks

**Update**: If I inspect the single product page, the script is present:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">
        {{{ data.variation.variation_description }}}
    </div>

    <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">
        {{{ data.variation.price_html }}}
    </div>

   <div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field">
        {{{ data.variation.text_field }}}
    </div>

    <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">
        {{{ data.variation.availability_html }}}
    </div>
</script>
```

---

The theme is [belise](https://themeforest.net/item/belise-exquisite-minimalist-restaurant-theme/19619976).

**Update**: I'm looking at the themes custom woocommerce `functions.php` (belise/inc/woocommerce/functions.php) file and the logic seems to be there.

```
/**
 * Shop page woocommerce-Price-amount amountption on product archives
 */
function belise_woocommerce_template_single_excerpt() {
    global $post;

    if ( ! $post->post_excerpt ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-Price-amount amountption" itemprop="woocommerce-Price-amount amountption">

        <!-- if I add <p>test</p> it is printed on the product page -->
        <!-- I would like for the custom field element to be printed here -->

        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_woocommerce-Price-amount amountption', $post->post_excerpt ); ?>
    </div><?php
}
```

**Answer** - @ClemC first solution works, the field didn't show because of the browsers cache.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For **serious** reference, see how WC itself adds the textarea `variable_description` to the variations [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-variation-admin.php#L305).

We notice multiple (potential) problems in your text field implementation.

- The **missing** `name`...
- The `id` string does **not** have a correct structure, it has the `name` structure instead...
- The `id` or `name` are **not** same than in your template...

So taking as reference the WC `variable_description` textarea implementation, let's implement our text field this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_settings_fields' );

function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'            => "my_text_field{$loop}",
            'name'          => "my_text_field[{$loop}]",
            'value'         => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'my_text_field', true ),
            'label'         => __( 'Some label', 'woocommerce' ),
            'desc_tip'      => true,
            'description'   => __( 'Some description.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'wrapper_class' => 'form-row form-row-full',
        )
    );
}

function save_variation_settings_fields( $variation_id, $loop ) {
    $text_field = $_POST['my_text_field'][ $loop ];

    if ( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'my_text_field', esc_attr( $text_field ));
    }
}

function load_variation_settings_fields( $variation ) {     
    $variation['my_text_field'] = get_post_meta( $variation[ 'variation_id' ], 'my_text_field', true );

    return $variation;
}
```

Now, in the template that **must have** the following path:

`yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-‌​cart/variation.php`

Add this:

```
<div class="random-class woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field">
    {{{ data.variation.my_text_field }}}
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**:

If you want to output your custom field the "classic" way:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-custom-text-field">
    <p><?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_text_field', true ) ); ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64305/discussion-on-answer-by-clemc-woocommerce-add-extra-field-to-variation-product).

Comment: @ClemC see the update.

Comment: @Vucko see the update.

Comment: It prints the `div` and the `p`, but the `p` is empty.

Comment: `var_dump(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_text_field', true ))` returns `string(0) ""` even if my custom field has a saved string.

Comment: I think it's because of the `$post->ID` which is not a variation and so for which you did not enter a `'my_text_field'` value. You really need to be inside the variation loop. From where you try to print the meta field, it seems the SAME meta field will be present for all variations and the main product itself, it's not what you want. The text field have to show only for its variation.

Comment: You really don't have much other choices than doing it with our first approach. I'd suggest you to go in chat room for troobleshooting your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64473/discussion-between-vucko-and-clemc).

Comment: This is great, thank you @ClemC - one small issue, I am able to edit the field text and re-save, however if I delete all contents and then save, it doesn't seem to save?

Comment: Ah, simply remove if ( ! empty( $field ) ) {} and it works. Any drawbacks to doing this?

Comment: After following a blog likely same as the op since it had the same code, you end up with the same problem.. If those blogs could proof read their codes we wouldn't be there