# Extending the woocommerce product export functionality

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, import, export

according to:

[Woocommerce add extra field to variation product](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276941/woocommerce-add-extra-field-to-variation-product/277556#277556?newreg=c2bbc427a5044b4984deb7abf95da2e3)

I can add additional fields to my variations. The question is, how can I export or import them via the build in importer/exporter.

Thank you